# installing ubuntu touch -unmet dependancies when installing ubuntu-flash-packagr using Precise or Trusty

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-touch, dependencies

in trying to install

> ubuntu-flash-package

(tried on both **Precise** and **Trusty**)

I get

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable
>                          Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli but it is not installable

searching for these packages [link here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ubuntu-snappy-cli&searchon=names) reveals that package

> ubuntu-snappy-cli

is only available after **wily**; is my only option to install **wily** or later?

I tried installing another PPA as suggested here [snappy bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1447733) but this did not work either.

Is an installation of **Wily** or **Xenial** my only option?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find these by using Y PPA;

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

this allows you to search for packages and download them; I don't know why but although I already had the repositories I could not get the packages.

Advice on installing / using Y PPA in a comprehensive answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

**if it helps please vote the linked answer up**